# JavaScript - What is the difference between "url.path" and "url.pathname"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

when creating server in `node.js` , the function has two arguments : request and response. Using request like this : `url.parse(request.url);` gives the url parts of the request that was sent , my question is :what is the difference between :  `url_parts.pathname;`  and `url_parts.path;` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/) is a good place to start: [`pathname`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_pathname) vs [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_urlobject_path): `pathname` is just the path portion of the URL; `path` is part of the legacy URL stuff and is the combination of the path portion and the search portion.